# node-fetch in discord.js cannot read property

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-fetch

I have been following the REST API guide from Discord.js, but I keep getting errors that the first property of the returning json cannot be read. I know that the api address is correct.

This is what the response looks like:
[image: response]

And here is my code:

**index.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const { prefix, token, api } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const trim = (str, max) => (str.length > max ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str);

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'div2') {
        if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send('You need to supply a search term!');
        }

        const query = querystring.stringify({ name: args.join(' ') });

        const { body } = await fetch(`${api}search.php?${query}&platform=uplay`)
            .then(response => response.json());         

        if (!body.results.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`No results found for **${args.join(' ')}**.`);
        }

        const [answer] = body.results;

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#EFFF00')
            .setTitle(answer.name)
            .addField('Platform', trim(answer.platform, 1024))
            .addField('Kills PvE', trim(answer.kills_npc, 1024));


        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

Comment: And whats the problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response `json` image does not have `body` property. So when do the `destructuring assignment`, there's no corresponding `body` in the response to assign to. So `body` is undefined.

Change your destructuring to:

```
const { results } = await fetch(`${api}search.php?${query}&platform=uplay`)
  .then(response => response.json());
// results is array from the response
```

Or simply; don't destructure (and you can leave the rest of the code as it is):

```
const body = await fetch(`${api}search.php?${query}&platform=uplay`)
  .then(response => response.json());
```